# Latex table multicolumn values are not centerd

Tags: latex

I'm trying to create a table with the following layout:
[image]

This is what I was able to do so far, as you can see there is too much space in my multicolumns(circled in red)
[image]

My code is:

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Different sampling strategies and the corresponding PRF scores, 
explain the scores!}             
\label{table:PRF_scores}      
\centering          
\begin{tabular}{c c | c c | l l l l }     % 7 columns 
\hline\hline       
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{sampling strategy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\emph{performance metrics}} \\                  
under\_sample & over\_sample & N_{memb} & N_{non-memb} & F1(\%) & 
ROC\_AUC(\%) PR\_AUC(\%) & MCC(\%)\\
\hline   
0.5 & 1.0 & 752 & 752 & 98.54 \pm 0.62 & 98.62 \pm 0.64 & 98.62 \pm 0.59 
& 97.08 \pm 1.25\\
0.1 & 1.0 & 3760 & 3760 & 99.09 \pm 0.17 & 99.08 \pm 0.18 & 99.09 \pm 
0.17 & 98.17 \pm 0.35\\
0.06 & 0.6 & 3759 & 6266 & 98.68 \pm 0.23 & 99.19 \pm 0.15 & 98.70 \pm 
0.23 & 97.89 \pm 0.37\\
\hline                  
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

What can I do to fix this issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using starred table? Can you include document class, preamble to show packages you use and document body, so we can compile your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a "re-designed" table.

First, I would avoid vertical bars, which IMO are rather distraction. Then, I moved group of `N` to the left; it doesn't seem to be a part of the other two groups and shouldn't be in the middle, does it? I also reduced wording in a few columns and added line breaks in long headers. This is one way to avoid overly wide and unbalanced tables.

Here is a list of helpful packages I applied to help me to format your table:

- `array` define column groups and additional column types
- `makecell` format cells and allows for line breaks, which I haven't had to use here
- `threeparttable` splits a table into three parts: caption, body, and annotation; also, keeps a table and its caption within boundaries
- `caption` adds options to format a caption
- `siunitx` formats and align numbers
- `booktabs` adds improved horizontal rules

Here's the screenshot

[image]

and the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \small
    % Settings for the caption
    \captionsetup{position=top, skip=3pt, format=hang}
    % Reduced horizontal spaces between columns 
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    % Slightly increased vertical spacing
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    % Settings for makecell 
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries\itshape}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{\Gape[0pt][0pt]}
    \renewcommand{\cellgape}{\Gape[3pt][0pt]}
    %
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Different sampling strategies and the corresponding PRF scores, explain the scores!}
        \label{table:PRF_scores}
        \begin{tabular}{
                *2{S[table-format=4]}
                @{\quad}
                *2{S[table-format=1.2]}
                *4{C{1.8cm}}
            }
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Strategy}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Performance metrics}} \\
            \cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-8}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{N$^{*}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sample} & F1   & ROC      & PR       & MCC \\[-3pt]
            {mem} & {n-mem}             & {under} & {over}           & (\%) & AUC (\%) & AUC (\%) & (\%) \\
            \midrule
             752 &  752 & 0.5  &  1.0 & 98.54 \pm 0.62 & 98.62 \pm 0.64 & 98.62 \pm 0.59 & 97.08 \pm 1.25 \\
            3760 & 3760 & 0.1  &  1.0 & 99.09 \pm 0.17 & 99.08 \pm 0.18 & 99.09 \pm 0.17 & 98.17 \pm 0.35\\
            3759 & 6266 & 0.06 &  0.6 & 98.68 \pm 0.23 & 99.19 \pm 0.15 & 98.70 \pm 0.23 & 97.89 \pm 0.37\\
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{8}{@{}l@{}}{%
                \makecell[l]{\footnotesize$^{*}$ The left column represents members of a group; the right
                    column the opposite}}
        \end{tabular}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```